# What is the Procedure for showing a webpage on my website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I want that other webpages are displayed on my website.
How should i proceed in that way ?

I made a webpage and used and Iframe. The iframe's scr is liked to a php file that uses the file_get_contents(URL) and echo's that to the screen.

The difficulty is that the links in the iframe would  pointing  to invalid references. 
So i think the `<BASE href>` tag would help

PROBLEM :

I want that the Java scrips to be used in the Iframe for manipulation of content.
The problem is that Java scrips wont wonk in the Iframe.

How can i make the JavaScript run in the Iframe ?

lastly i want that the content manipulated in the Iframe is saved. 
so how can i write the content of the Iframe ?

Is the procedure that i am using Right ? or is there some other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PHProxy, this PHP app fetch the webpage and convert all urls for you.
You should just pass it url. you can keep it in iframe or not.

Comment: i want that the content manipulated in the Iframe or the proxy is saved. so how can i save that  ?

Comment: take a look at PHProxy source code, you can simply save fetched content before output to client.